# How can I pass my own classes as arguments when using a python function in a co.Exec node?

Tags: python, conducto

I am trying to pass my own user-defined class as a parameter when adding a Exec node like `co.Exec(my_func, a=my_class)`. This doesn't seem to be working out of the box, however. Are there any serialization/de-serialization functions I can write to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `to_str` instance method to serialize, and a `from_str` staticmethod to deserialize.

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

    def to_str(self):
        return repr(self.value)

    @staticmethod
    def from_str(val):
        value = ast.literal_eval(val)
        return MyClass(value)
```

This `eval`/`repr` combo is trivial and you might be wondering why it doesn't just use JSON or `pickle`. This feature is intended for things like database IDs of complex objects, where the object is too large or complex to fully serialize but is easy to reconstruct from its name.

A clearer example might be a daily time series of a financial instrument:

```
class time_series:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = ... # Look up data in some data store

    def to_str(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod
    def from_str(value):
        return time_series(value)
```

This can be used to write very natural code and command lines. Take the following example:

```
def plot(ts: time_series):
    "Plot the given time series"
    # Implementation omitted; it isn't really the interesting part
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    co.main()
```

To plot a `time_series`, pass this class normally, as in:

```
aapl = time_series("AAPL.US")
plot(aapl)
```

To make a node that plots it, pass it to co.Exec: `co.Exec(plot, aapl)`.

To plot from the command line, call `python <file> plot --ts=AAPL.US` and `co.main` will deserialize the name "AAPL.US" and call `plot()` with a rich `time_series` object.